# Как в React загружать картинки + добавить кастомные поля?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ребята, приветствую . Возник вопрос c которым пока не могу разобраться. В разработке сервис , который будет работать с картинками. В нем будет функционал по созданию/редактирования пака и созданию/удалению картинки в паке . Нужно создать компонент , который будет загружать картинку + возможность добавить теги, название , в превью картинки вывести доп.информацию (форматы картинки). Встречал компонент upload https://ant.design/components/upload/ , но пока не нашел возможности кастомизировать этот компонент : добавить кастомные поля и как-то выводить данные в превью. Подскажите , какие есть возможности реализовать загрузку картинок + заполнение кастомынх полей ? может есть похожие примеры , где можно что-то подсмотреть для себя ?) Заранее спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]